# Convert bytes to base 10 number by keeping digits in tact

Tags: solidity, bytes, uint256

I have a very weird use case. Tl;dr I'm trying to convert a bytes16 to a base 10 integer by keeping the digits in tact.

i.e `0x00000000000000000000000002987391` should become `2987391`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the hex numbers are between 0-9, you can use one of the two functions below (the first one is more gas efficient, while the second function is more human readable). The output can be reduced to uint112 if needed since the max number is `0x99999999999999999999999999999999`.

```
function hex2Base10Assembly (bytes16 input) public pure returns (uint output) {
    
    uint power10 = 1;

    assembly {
        input := shr(128, input)
        for { let i := 0 } lt(i, 31) { i := add(i, 1) } {
            output := add(output, mul(mod(input, 16), power10)) 
            input := div(input, 16)
            power10 := mul(power10, 10)
        }             
        output := add(output, mul(mod(input, 16), power10))   
    }
    return output;
}
```

Human readable:

```
function hex2Base10 (bytes16 hexInput) public pure returns (uint output) {

    uint power10 = 1;

    uint128 input = uint128(hexInput);

    for(uint i; i < 31; ++i) {
        output = output + (input % 16) * power10;
        input = input / 16;
        power10 = power10 * 10;
    }

    output = output + (input % 16) * power10;

    return output;
}
```